# How to get multi matching filters count in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have around 50000 documents in collection. Collections Schema looks like this:

```
{ param1: Boolean, param2: Boolean, param3: Boolean, param4: Boolean } //etc
```

How should i make query to db, to get each matching param count.
Currently, I'm calling each param in a loop:

```
db.getCollection('patients').count({ param1: true } )
db.getCollection('patients').count({ param2: true } )
db.getCollection('patients').count({ param3: true } ) ...
```

I feel, this isn't right way, please give me some advise, how to get this information in one query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very possible in one go via the **[aggregation framework](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-introduction/)**.

With MongoDb 3.6 and newer, you can leverage the use of **[`$arrayToObject`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/)** operator within a **[`$replaceRoot`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/)** pipeline to get the desired result.

Within the pipeline, take advantage of the [**`$cond`**](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/#exp._S_cond) operator in the [**`$group`**](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group) stage to evaluate the counts based on the param field boolean value, something like the following:

```
db.getCollection('patients').aggregate([ 
    { "$project": { "_id": 0 } },
    { "$project": { "data": { "$objectToArray": "$$ROOT" } } },
    { "$unwind": "$data" },
    { "$group": { 
        "_id": "$data.k", 
        "count": { 
            "$sum": {
                "$cond": [ "$data.v", 1, 0 ] 
            }
        } 
    } },
    { "$group": { 
        "_id": null, 
        "counts": { 
            "$push": { "k": "$_id", "v": "$count" } 
        } 
    } }, 
    { "$project": { 
        "data": { "$arrayToObject": "$counts" } 
    } }, 
    { "$replaceRoot": { "newRoot": "$data" } } 
])
```

---

For MongoDB versions that do not have support for the above **[`$arrayToObject`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/)** and **[`$replaceRoot`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/)** operators, you would need to explicitly specify the fields in the group pipeline when calculating the sums:

```
db.getCollection('patients').aggregate([    
    { "$group": { 
        "_id": null,             
        "param1_count": {
            "$sum": {
                "$cond": [ "$param1", 1, 0 ] /* similar to "$cond": [ { "$eq": [ "$param1", true ] }, 1, 0 ] */
            }
        },
        "param2_count": {
            "$sum": {
                "$cond": [ "$param2", 1, 0 ]
            }
        },
        "param3_count": {
            "$sum": {
                "$cond": [ "$param3", 1, 0 ]
            }
        },
        "param4_count": {
            "$sum": {
                "$cond": [ "$param4", 1, 0 ]
            }
        } 
    } },
    { "$project": {
        "_id": 0,             
        "param_counts": {
            "param1": "$param1_count",
            "param2": "$param2_count",
            "param3": "$param3_count",
            "param4": "$param4_count"
        }
    } }
])
```